# Weblogic server down with outofmemory

Tags: weblogic-10.x

Is there any way to pro actively find like 'my server will down with out of memory in after some minutes.'

Is there any steps to find that. Want to know my server is going to down with out of memory in few minutes. before its occurring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe one of the only solutions is to keep an eye on the log files.  There is the standard error message which is written to the log files at a defined time interval '% of the server memory is free'.  If this figure is consistently low and shrinking then you know there is something wrong.

[This](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/apirefs.1111/e13952/taskhelp/monitoring/LogLowMemoryConditions.html) document also suggests extra methods to add logging and increase alert levels for low memory conditions.